# Parsing an input separated by delimiter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am developing a PHP application for online code judge.
For the same, I am taking input passing it on to a Java server calculating the output and then again matching the generated output with the desired output.
As for now it works only for a single input or output.

I want to extend it such that multiple inputs can be parsed to Java server and the output obtained are matched with the respective desired output.

```
$input = str_replace("\n", '$_n_$', treat($fields['input'])); //$fields has result of SQL query
fwrite($socket, $input."\n"); // write input to the socket
```

As of now I have input like :
INPUT

> 1 2 3 4 5

OUTPUT(in this case sum)

```
15
```

This input is matched with expected output i have already

Now what i want is, if the input is :

```
1 2 3 4 5

#
1  3 5 7

#
1 2 6 7
```

I want that at once only one input is passed to jave server ,then another and so on.
The inputs can be separated by any delimiter in this case I have used #.

How do I proceed with it?
Should I use associative arrays?

Comment: try with a single, specific delimiter first. It's not that hard. Then, the answer for multiple delimiters will be at your grasp. you need to learn to walk before you can learn to run

Comment: @STTLCU can i use the explode function?

Comment: yeah. Explode would be the first attempt. With a single, defined separator it's ideal.